# Django project is corrupted

Tags: python, django

I have a new project for a little online shop. I use the PyCharm code editor. It saves the progress whenever I switch to a new window and the server autorestarts. After a while of working on the project the server stopped doing that and now it needs to be done manually. When I got to making forms, I noticed that they don't show on the page. It's the same logic as in my previews projects. I made exactly the same forms and models from the old project in the current one and they do not work. Then I did the opposite: I added the models and the form from the current project into the old one and they do render on page.

What could be the problem and where shoul I start looking for it?

Comment: PyCharm does not restart the server, the server does that by itself if you set `DEBUG = True`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the point is that it saves the files whenever I switch windows

Comment: have you checked in `settings > Apperance and behaviour > System settings > Save files when switching to a different app or built in terminal` to ensure this is still checked

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes, that's not the problem